# An example from multiple source files in Doxygen

Tags: doxygen

I am documenting a group of classes that work together using Doxygen and I wrote an example spread across multiple source files (All referenced from `EXAMPLE_PATH`). More precisely, I wrote the following:

```
/*************************************//**
 * Some context...
 *  @example Source1.cpp
 *
 * More context...
 *  @example Source2.cpp
 ****************************************/
```

The problem is that the output is spread in half in the Example page generated by Doxygen (a page for Source1, another for Source2). I would like it to be all on the same HTML page, with the context and example code together as one tutorial:

```
Some context...
|----------------------------------------------|
| int main()                                   |
| {                                            |
|   //...                                      |
| }                                            |
|----------------------------------------------|

More context...
|----------------------------------------------|
| bool fct()                                   |
| {                                            |
|   //...                                      |
| }                                            |
|----------------------------------------------|
```

Is there a way to accomplish this? I am using Doxygen 1.8.11.

Regards

Comment: Can give a bit a more detailed information. e.g. small Source1.cpp and Source2.cpp (just 1 or 2 lines in the files is sufficient), the current output and the output you would like to have? Which version of doxygen are you using?

Comment: @albert just updated. Does this help?

Comment: I now got it (I think), the examples are shown on separate pages. Did you have a look at \verbinclude and \include, also \snippet might give some possibilities?

Comment: Also try to update to version 1.8.13.

Comment: @albert I have tried \include but the page does not appear under the Example section (In fact I haven't found where it went)... It also seems 1.8.11-1 is the latest available on Xubuntu unless I do a manual install, which I would like to avoid since other people might want to build it as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found a semi-legit solution: if you add the `@example` tag at the beginning and use `@include`s afterwards, it works:

```
/*************************************//**
 * @example "My tutorial"
 * 
 * Some context...
 *  @include Source1.cpp
 *
 * More context...
 *  @include Source2.cpp
 ****************************************/
```

However, looking at the error output from Doxygen I get the following message: `warning: included file My is not found. Check your EXAMPLE_PATH`

The solution is not clean, but is usable for the time being. If you have a better suggestion (i.e. warning removed), please share it and I will accept it.

Comment: Contrary to the documentation it looks like if you omit the file name that it does not output a warning. What actually is requited is something like \example this "Header".

Comment: @albert I have tried this and it seems that if you omit the file name, Doxygen assumes the file name is the current file name (where the above code lies). If you have code in that file that is not related, it will be included.